# Underscore.js causing Angularjs $digest to abort

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

I'm trying to group an array of objects by the first letter of an arbitrary field name, though I've had this issue other times I've tried to use `underscore.js`.

Here's an example plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/xt9ahm1dSLa0xVMxW5QA

I have a list of items (`$scope.items`) and I'm using an `ng-repeat` to iterate over them after passing them through some filters. The filter is using `underscore.js` `groupBy` to return an object with properties for each group (see example at bottom of `app.js`).

When I try to use the filter I hit the `10 $digest() iterations reached, Aborting!` exception.

I have some idea of why its happening, the filter must be modifying the underlying objects content which `AngularJS` picks up on and then tries to re-run the filter. I'm not sure where this modification is happening though:

- Is it something internal to `_.js` that I can't control?
- Is there some special setup I have to do before I attempt to process an array in a filter? 
  Some kind of `scope.$unwatch`?
- Why does Angularjs's own `orderBy` not cause this?

Comment: Take a look at [this Google Group reply](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/IEIQok-YkpU/InEXv61MrkMJ)--it will explain why what you're trying to do is difficult in a filter.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll go about using a controller method instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As linked by BinaryMuse, this [Google Groups link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/IEIQok-YkpU/InEXv61MrkMJ) explains why this happens.